# working with sqlce and ErikEJ.SqlCe library

Tags: dll, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

i got this errors

```
Error 1 The type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction' is defined in an assembly is not referenced That. You Must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 89845dcd8080cc91'.
```

WHERE DO I DOWNLOAD VERSION 4.0.0.0? I didn't find it.

```
Error   2   The type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'.
```

same problem..

```
Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer (System.Data.DataTable)' Some invalid arguments have
```

overloaded? only i want to use it :s

```
Error   88  The best overloaded method match for 'ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopy.WriteToServer(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments
```

?? it DOES allow datatable . i dont understand it..

```
Error   94  Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataTable [c:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.dll]' to 'System.Data.DataTable []'
```

convert to datatable[]?? what?

well this is my method code.

private void DoBulkCopy(bool keepNulls, System.Data.DataTable tabla, string nombretabla)
    {
        if (tabla.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

```
        ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopyOptions options = new ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopyOptions();
        if (keepNulls)
        {
            options = options |= ErikEJ.SqlCe.SqlCeBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls;
        }
        //using (SqlCeBulkCopy bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connectionString, options))

        using (SqlCeBulkCopy bc = new SqlCeBulkCopy(Resco.Data.Database.Instance.ConnectionString,options))
        {

            bc.DestinationTableName = nombretabla;

            try
            {
                bc.WriteToServer(tabla);
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { }
        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Which DLL are you using - is this on windows mobile, then use ErikEJ.SqlCeBulkCopyCF.dll

Comment: that doesn't exist i have 4: ErikEj.SqlCe.dll, ErikEj.SqlCe.NetCF.dll, ErikEj.SqlCe40.dll and salient.data.dll now it runs but i got this new error File or assembly name 'System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, i am using ErikEj.SqlCe.NetCF.dll

Comment: @ErikEJ i got this message "{The operation completed successfully.}" but none rows was added, does it acept a connections string with double \\? this is my connections string "Data source=\\Program Files\\Venta_AP\\Data\\Database.sdf"

Answer (score 0):

Easy way -> install to project using Package Manager Console.

```
PM> Install-Package ErikEJ.SqlCeBulkCopy
```

See http://nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.SqlCeBulkCopy

Comment: That will not install the Compact Framework library, as NuGet does not support Compact Framework